# What causes a GCP Cloud Functions response error?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCP Cloud Function which is triggered via a Pub/sub topic. The function just backs up Datastore data to Cloud storage. The function works fine but I get a
`Function execution took 933 ms. Finished with status: response error` and I don't understand why? As far as I understand I follow what is in the [GCP Docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime#signal-termination).

My code looks like this:

```
/* receives pub/sub message which is triggered every 24h. 
*/
exports.subscribe = async (message, context) => {
    console.log('CHRON HANDLER STARTED');
    await this.backupDB();
    return Promise.resolve();
}

const bucket = 'gs://XXX_db_backups';

exports.backupDB = async () => {
    try {
        const databaseName = client.databasePath('XXX', '(default)');
        await client.exportDocuments({
            name: databaseName,
            outputUriPrefix: bucket,
            collectionIds: ['backuptest', ],
        });    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('DB BACKUP SUCCESS');
  };
```

**EDIT 1**
The complete error message is:
`2022-04-09T10:30:15.076043374Z test-chron-handler yuthy3qj84sr Function execution took 933 ms. Finished with status: response error`
Actually it is not even flagged as an error in the Cloud Functions log, it is just a regular status message that logs that the function ended. But as you can see the finishing status is indeed an error.

Comment: What happens if you remove `return Promise.resolve()";`

Comment: Same error then too.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `exports.subscribe = async pubsubMessage => {}` ?

Comment: Can you give the complete error message, if any, including status code.

Comment: I have updated the post with the complete error message, although it doesn't contain much more info besides what I originally wrote.

Comment: I have the same issue with Firebase Functions, the function completes without any response but still there is an debug message stating `Finished with status: "response error"`.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the error status by deploying the function with node v16 instead of v14.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is a current known issue when a function returns anything but a 200. Even 201 and 204 give response error in the logs. It seems to only affect the logs and not the actual response. I've verified this in my setup.

In this SO question:

[GCP logs show function "Function execution took xxx ms. Finished with status: response error" whenever my header status code is not 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869587/gcp-logs-show-function-function-execution-took-xxx-ms-finished-with-status-re)

The following comment was written:

> The product team is aware of this issue and they have updated today
> that the change is reverted back, you can expect the previous behavior
> to be resumed shortly. Let me know if you face any errors after a day
> or two. – Priyashree Bhadra Apr 19 at 11:02

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when the response size from the functions exceeds 10MB [1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits). I think you hit the max response size which is 10 MB for functions.

For more information please go through these stackoverflow links [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510125/firebase-admin-failing-to-query-large-items) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865573/firebase-cloud-function-finished-with-status-response-error).

Comment: This is correct if the function is triggered on an http request since you then may send an http response with data. But in. my case the function is event triggered and does therefore not send any response data at all.

Comment: @jola "I suspect that this issue is from the cloud functions side", You may contact support by visiting this link: https://cloud.google.com/support/